Okta SAML 2.0 Sign-Out Not Prompting for Re-Login in ASP.NET Application
I working with Okta SAML 2.0 authentication in my ASP.NET C# application using the package from itfoxtec.com. Authentication works fine, but I'm having issues with the sign-out functionality.
When I sign out, I am successfully redirected to the logout URL, but after re-logging in, Okta doesn't prompt for credentials again. It seems to be using the existing session and auto-logs the user back in.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Implemented the LogoutRequest as per Okta SAML 2.0 documentation
Made sure the session in my application is cleared after logout.
Attempted setting the SessionIndex during logout to invalidate the session at the Okta end.
Ensured that I’m hitting the proper Okta logout endpoint, but the session still persists.
Tried using this as a redirect link : https://your_tenant.okta.com/login/signout?fromURI=your_redirect_here - but the rediection is not working

Is there a way to force Okta to prompt for credentials after logging out? Is there something I am missing in the SAML sign-out process?
